# Neo4j Page Cache Index Issue for multiple graphservices

Tags: java, neo4j, lucene

I've been using the neo4j version 3.3.3 with java embedded connection.

I can use a single graphservice (single database) without any issue.

I want to copy few nodes from one graphservice to a new graphservice (a second database - testdb2).

Sample code:

```
    String test="/home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db";
    String test2="/home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/test2.db";


    GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(new File(test));
    GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService2 = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(new File(test2));
```

However i've the next exception:

```
org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.pagecache.PageCacheLifecycle@6e807e2' failed to transition from stopped to shutting_down. Please see the attached cause exception "Cannot close the PageCache while files are still mapped:
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/test2.db/neostore.nodestore.db.labels (1 mapping)".
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:519)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:206)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.ClassicCoreSPI.shutdown(ClassicCoreSPI.java:175)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.shutdown(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:387)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:220)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:126)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:137)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:130)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:193)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:75)
    at pt.uminho.eng.pdebiom.humanmmintegration.TestNeo4j.test(TestNeo4j.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
    Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/test2.db
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:211)
        ... 30 more
    Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource@389a5022' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "/home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/test2.db/neostore.nodestore.db.id (Too many open files)".
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:466)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:100)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:207)
        ... 30 more
    Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.UnderlyingStorageException: Unable to create id file /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/test2.db/neostore.nodestore.db.id
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.id.IdContainer.createEmptyIdFile(IdContainer.java:313)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.id.IdContainer.init(IdContainer.java:88)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.id.IdGeneratorImpl.<init>(IdGeneratorImpl.java:108)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.id.DefaultIdGeneratorFactory.instantiate(DefaultIdGeneratorFactory.java:69)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.id.DefaultIdGeneratorFactory.open(DefaultIdGeneratorFactory.java:61)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.id.BufferingIdGeneratorFactory.open(BufferingIdGeneratorFactory.java:69)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.id.BufferingIdGeneratorFactory.open(BufferingIdGeneratorFactory.java:61)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.CommonAbstractStore.openIdGenerator(CommonAbstractStore.java:682)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.CommonAbstractStore.loadIdGenerator(CommonAbstractStore.java:365)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.CommonAbstractStore.loadStorage(CommonAbstractStore.java:228)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.CommonAbstractStore.checkAndLoadStorage(CommonAbstractStore.java:211)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.CommonAbstractStore.initialise(CommonAbstractStore.java:133)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.initialize(NeoStores.java:262)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.createNodeStore(NeoStores.java:538)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreType$2.open(StoreType.java:47)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreType$2.open(StoreType.java:42)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.openStore(NeoStores.java:255)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.getOrCreateStore(NeoStores.java:300)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.<init>(NeoStores.java:144)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.openNeoStores(StoreFactory.java:156)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.openAllNeoStores(StoreFactory.java:120)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine.<init>(RecordStorageEngine.java:197)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.buildStorageEngine(NeoStoreDataSource.java:579)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:445)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
        ... 35 more
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/test2.db/neostore.nodestore.db.id (Too many open files)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
        at org.neo4j.io.fs.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.open(DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.java:69)
        at org.neo4j.io.fs.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.create(DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.java:100)
        at org.neo4j.io.fs.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.create(DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.java:54)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.id.IdContainer.createEmptyIdFile(IdContainer.java:302)
        ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot close the PageCache while files are still mapped:
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/test2.db/neostore.nodestore.db.labels (1 mapping)
    at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCache.close(MuninnPageCache.java:573)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.pagecache.PageCacheLifecycle.shutdown(PageCacheLifecycle.java:42)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:511)
    ... 34 more
```

I have already give the 777 permissions to the first database folder.

If I invert the order of graphservice to be loaded:

```
String test="/home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db";
String test2="/home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/test2.db";

GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService2 = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(new File(test2));
GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(new File(test));
```

I have the next exception:

```
    org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.pagecache.PageCacheLifecycle@62a6674f' failed to transition from stopped to shutting_down. Please see the attached cause exception "Cannot close the PageCache while files are still mapped:
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/schema/index/lucene_native-1.0/1331/native-1.0/index-1331 (1 mapping) 

    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/schema/index/lucene_native-1.0/8/native-1.0/index-8 (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/schema/index/lucene_native-1.0/1/native-1.0/index-1 (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/neostore (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/neostore.counts.db.a (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/neostore.relationshipgroupstore.db (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/neostore.schemastore.db (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/neostore.labeltokenstore.db (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/neostore.labeltokenstore.db.names (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/neostore.relationshipstore.db (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/neostore.propertystore.db (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/neostore.propertystore.db.arrays (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/neostore.propertystore.db.strings (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/neostore.propertystore.db.index (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/neostore.nodestore.db (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/neostore.nodestore.db.labels (1 mapping)".
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:519)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:206)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.ClassicCoreSPI.shutdown(ClassicCoreSPI.java:175)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.shutdown(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:387)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:220)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:126)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:137)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:130)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:193)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:75)
    at pt.uminho.eng.pdebiom.humanmmintegration.TestNeo4j.test(TestNeo4j.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
    Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:211)
        ... 30 more
    Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine@50bc3219' failed to initialize. Please see the attached cause exception "/home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/schema/index/lucene_native-1.0/1338/lucene-1.0/failure-message (Too many open files)".
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:427)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:62)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:98)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:521)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:100)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:207)
        ... 30 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/schema/index/lucene_native-1.0/1338/lucene-1.0/failure-message (Too many open files)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.storage.FailureStorage.loadIndexFailure(FailureStorage.java:103)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.storage.PartitionedIndexStorage.getStoredIndexFailure(PartitionedIndexStorage.java:136)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.schema.LuceneSchemaIndexProvider.getInitialState(LuceneSchemaIndexProvider.java:129)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.schema.fusion.FusionSchemaIndexProvider.getInitialState(FusionSchemaIndexProvider.java:113)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.IndexingService.lambda$init$1(IndexingService.java:195)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.IndexMapReference.modify(IndexMapReference.java:51)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.IndexingService.init(IndexingService.java:184)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine.init(RecordStorageEngine.java:404)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:406)
        ... 39 more
        Suppressed: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Exception during graceful attempt to shutdown partially initialized component. Please use non suppressed exception to see original component failure.
            at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:418)
            ... 39 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.labelscan.NativeLabelScanStore.shutdown(NativeLabelScanStore.java:470)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine.shutdown(RecordStorageEngine.java:451)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:414)
            ... 39 more
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/schema/index/lucene_native-1.0/1338/lucene-1.0/failure-message (Too many open files)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
        at org.neo4j.io.fs.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.open(DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.java:69)
        at org.neo4j.io.fs.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.open(DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.java:54)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.storage.FailureStorage.isFailed(FailureStorage.java:167)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.storage.FailureStorage.loadIndexFailure(FailureStorage.java:95)
        ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot close the PageCache while files are still mapped:
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/schema/index/lucene_native-1.0/1331/native-1.0/index-1331 (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/schema/index/lucene_native-1.0/1324/native-1.0/index-1324 (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/schema/index/lucene_native-1.0/1317/native-1.0/index-1317 (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/schema/index/lucene_native-1.0/1310/native-1.0/index-1310 (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/neostore.labeltokenstore.db.names (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/neostore.relationshipstore.db (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/neostore.propertystore.db (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/neostore.propertystore.db.arrays (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/neostore.propertystore.db.strings (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/neostore.propertystore.db.index (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/neostore.nodestore.db (1 mapping)
    /home/rrodrigues/work/applications/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/nocompartment.db/neostore.nodestore.db.labels (1 mapping)
    at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCache.close(MuninnPageCache.java:573)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.pagecache.PageCacheLifecycle.shutdown(PageCacheLifecycle.java:42)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:511)
    ... 34 more
```

Is this a issue related with Lucene PageCache for multiple database indexes?